# Filter Out Rows with Matching Substring

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that returns rows that resemble this:

```
R123
R234
R345
J123
```

Is it possible to have the rows that have matching substrings to not be returned? So in this case R123 and J123 would not be shown in the results.

Comment: Define "similar". Is that rows that has the same numerical-part and any preceding char?

Comment: Rows that match from the second character position to the end. R123 would be the receipt, J123 would be the journal entry and since they essentially cancel themselves out they shouldn't be returned.

Comment: How do you know J123 belongs to R123?  If its a journal entry, couldn't it be for another transaction?  Or is there more identifying information in the table?

Comment: Nope, the only thing that denotes it as a journal entry is the 'J' followed by a string of digits that match the receipt, which would start with an 'R'.

Comment: The RIGHT() function, which will return the n right-most characters, may help.  example: select RIGHT(fieldname, 3) would return the last 3 characters. Without more information about your table structure I cannot provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but it should give you an idea..

Inner join the receipts i.e. subset of the table where left(col,1) = 'r'
with the journals (subset of the table where left(col,1) = 'j) and you'll get a list of matching rows.

Then simply select the rows from the table which are not in this list

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] 
WHERE SUBSTRING(col,2,100) NOT IN 
    (SELECT Receipts.Ref FROM 
           (SELECT SUBSTRING(col,2,100) Ref from [Table] WHERE LEFT(col,1) = 'R') Receipts
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING(col,2,100) Ref from [Table] WHERE LEFT(col,1) = 'J') Journals ON Receipts.Ref = Journals.Ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  Value
from MyTable
group by substring(Value,2,len(Value))
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, how about this?

```
create table t1 (
t varchar(20) 
)

go
insert into t1 (t) values ('R123'),('R234'),('R345'),('J123')
go

select Numerals 
from (
    select SUBSTRING(t,1,1) as Prefix, SUBSTRING(t,2,999) as Numerals
    from t1) a
group by Numerals
having COUNT(*) = 1
```